# How to get IConfiguration in .NET Core without passing in the constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a .NET Core application and I need to access IConfiguration in different classes of my project without passing it in the constructor. I suppose I should use Dependency Injection, but I'm not sure how to do it correctly. I understand, this question could be consider as duplicate. I have read so many questions about my problem. But I think I am something missing or doing it wrong way..

in **Program.cs**

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
               {
                   webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                   webBuilder.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                   {
                       logging.ClearProviders();
                       logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.None);
                   });
               });
```

**Startup.cs**

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<EshopContext>();
            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);

        }
    }
```

**EshopContext.cs**

```
public class EshopContext: DbContext
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public EshopContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("connString")!; 

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }


    }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  You indicate *"without passing it in the constructor"* but in the code shown an `IConfiguration` object is expected on the `EshopContext` constructor.  Is this not working in some way?  Or it is working but you want to remove it from the constructor signature?  If so, why?  Or are you asking something else entirely?  Please elaborate on the problem you've encountered with the code shown.

Comment: I want to use `IConfiguration`, but in my situation. Whenewer I creat object `EshopContext c = new()`, it tells me to deliver `IConfiguration` for this constructor.  `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'configuration' `

Comment: Where/why are you manually creating an instance of the DB context?  Shouldn't that *also* be provided via dependency injection?  (Which would allow the dependency injection system to supply it with the parameters it needs.)  Alternatively, where you manually create that instance, can't *that* class receive an instance of `IConfiguration` on *its* constructor, and supply that instance to the DB context?

Comment: You normally wouldn't instantiate your own DbContexts, you would typically register it as a transient or scoped service, and then get it from DI or from a service provider. More reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/

Comment: @Luke Okay, this was consider as example. I meant it whenewer I create any Object with `IConfiguration`

Comment: Any object that requires an `IConfiguration` instance should either itself be instantiated by DI, or by another DI provided service. Anything other scenario is probably an antipattern. `IConfiguration` isn't statically provided so there's not really any other (good) way to get it.

Comment: @Peter_Griffindor: And what object are you creating which (1) needs an instance of `IConfiguration`, (2) needs to *not* be created by the dependency injection system (why?), and (3) needs to *not* be created by an object which itself wasn't created by the dependency injection system (why?).  If you're struggling to create even a contrived example of the problem, that's usually a good indication that you've made a false assumption about the problem somewhere.  At this time it's not clear why you need to manually create an instance of `IConfiguration`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For EF Core there are several methods to register database contexts so you don't need to work with configuration directly. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core):

Change the ctor to accept `DbContextOptions<TContext>`

```
public class EshopContext : DbContext
{
    public EshopContext(DbContextOptions<EshopContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

And then register it:

```
services.AddDbContext<EshopContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("connString")));
```

For other cases I would recommend to check out the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options) (basically you register special type for every class requiring something from config and bind it from the config during the registration time). Also I recommend to take a look at the [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) article.

Comment: This looks like something I am looking for `services.AddDbContext<EshopContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("connString")));
` Should I this use in `DbContext`

Comment: @Peter_Griffindor not fully following the question. To support `AddDbContext` `EshopContext` should have ctor with `DbContextOptions<EshopContext> options` parameter.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, so what will be in the `OnConfiguring ` method in `EshopContext`?

Comment: @Peter_Griffindor nothing. In general case it is not needed with this pattern and can be removed.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the default behavior of `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` includes the `OnConfiguring` method. It can be disabled with the `--no-onconfiguring` option, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/#connection-strings-in-the-scaffolded-code